# Django change password without logging again

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

In my system users first enter the system and must change their password.
I have a view that changes the password, The problem is when the page reloads the user session is lost and forces the user to log in again.
I do not know how to change this behavior. An overview of my code

views.py

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.body
        change = json.loads(data)
        id = change["id"]
        password = change["password"]
        user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=id)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse('success')

 def login_success(request):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name="group1").exists():
        return redirect(group1)
    elif request.user.groups.filter(name="group2").exists():
        return redirect(group2)
    elif request.user.groups.filter(name="group3").exists():
        return redirect(group3)
    else:
        return redirect(group4)
```

I'm using a CustomUser Model

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    ...
    login = models.BooleanField(_('login'), default=False, blank=True)    
    ...
```

In my Templates.

```
{% if user.login %}
    <h1>Hi User</h1>

{% else %}

    <form name="changePass" method="post">

    </form> 
{% endif %}
```

I need the user remains logged in even after changing the password, I do within the templates is to change the status of the login variable in my customuser.

I appreciate any answers or help, Thanks, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since version 1.7, Django has introduced a new feature that invalidates the current session when you update a password from a user.
You can see more about it in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change

All you have to do to avoid the logout is call the method `update_session_auth_hash` from `django.contrib.auth` as the example from the documentation:

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash


def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
    else:
        ...
```